# Does stroke to path essentially create two different objects?

Tags: vector, inkscape

In inkscape does stroke to path essentially create two different objects?

For example if we have a square with a stroke and we do `object to path` and then `stroke to path` we can now manipulate the "Fill" and the "Stroke" as if they were separate objects.  Are they still linked in any way?

[This is a time market youtube link that shows a demo that illustrates the question](https://youtu.be/JEPd-gCW5m8?t=176).

IIUC they are still linked in the sense that if we click on the select tool, we will be selecting the whole thing.  If we then do `path> break apart` then we get two separate objects?

Kind of a broad question - just trying to get a better grip on what the commands are for / underlying semantics.

Comment: The video shows a trick Nick Saporito often uses. He converts the stroke to a path: one single object, but with an outer edge and an inner edge. Then he does "Break apart", which converts the inner edge to a path of its own. Now there are two objects: the former outer and the former inner paths. Then he turns that into one path again using "Union". Fact is that until the upcoming version 1.0, stroke-to-path only generates one object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object to path removes path effects and generates a bezier curve which looks the same. Texts and Inkscape's preset shapes such as rectangles and ellipses aren't initially bezier curves when one draws them. For example path effects do not function with them. After applying object to path they become bezier curves and path effects & path editing tools work with them.

Objects can have a stroke. Stroke to path generates a path (=a closed bezier curve, single or combined) which covers the same area as the stroke and has the same fill color as the stroke had. You can insert a stroke to a path which was originally a stroke.

If you have a filled shape with a stroke and apply stroke to path, the fill disappears and you have a closed path which covers the area of the former stroke. The path is a combined one, because it has a hole. If you apply Path > Break Apart, you get the hole area as a different filled path.

Comment: In 1.0, stroke-to-path will create an object that consists of (optionally) 3 different object types: 1. the stroke as a path, like above, 2. the fill as a path, if there is one, 3. the markers as paths or groups, if there were any.

Comment: Inkscape 1.0 HERE WE GO!!!  I made that up all by myself :)